# Js or jquery for disabling multiple lower values in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Js or jquery code for disabling values which are  present lower to the selected value in other dropdownlist and remaining values i.e greater than selected should display in other dropdownlist

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                           <select name="time_from" id="time_from" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Preferred Time From</option>
                            <option value="06:00">6:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="07:00">7:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="08:00">8:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="09:00">9:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="10:00">10:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="11:00">11:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="12:00">12:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="13:00">01:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="14:00">02:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="15:00">03:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="16:00">04:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="17:00">05:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="18:00">06:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="19:00">07:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="20:00">08:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="21:00">09:00 PM</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                           <select name="time_to" id="time_to" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Preferred Time To</option>
                            <option value="07:00">7:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="08:00">8:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="09:00">9:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="10:00">10:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="11:00">11:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="12:00">12:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="13:00">01:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="14:00">02:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="15:00">03:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="16:00">04:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="17:00">05:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="18:00">06:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="19:00">07:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="20:00">08:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="21:00">09:00 PM</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
```

I had two selection tags.., in 1st selection i have choosed 09:00 suppose then in 2nd dropdown it should display only the greater values to 09:00

Comment: Please show your HTML, or similar sample code. We need some idea of what you want to do.

Comment: Is there something you've tried already to achiev this? This is not a coding service!

Comment: Just a recommendation, I would lose the :00 in the value and do a less than check on the values in a for each loop. But as Jeff said, you have to give it a go, can't just ask for the code.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#student_form").find('#time_from').on("change",function () {
        var prev_value =  $("#student_form").find('#time_from').val();
 $("#student_form").find('#student_form').find('option').each(function(){
  if($(this).val()== prev_value)
  {
   $(this).attr('style','color:red');
   $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  }
  else
  {
   $(this).attr('style','color:inherit');
   $(this).attr('disabled', false);
  }
 });
  
    });
}); I have used that disable current value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with jQuery this way

```js
$('#time_from').change(function(){

  var time_from = $(this).val();
  
  $('#time_to').find('option').filter(function()   {
       
      return $(this).attr('disabled', $(this).val() <= time_from) 
     
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
                           <select name="time_from" id="time_from" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Preferred Time From</option>
                            <option value="06:00">6:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="07:00">7:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="08:00">8:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="09:00">9:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="10:00">10:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="11:00">11:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="12:00">12:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="13:00">01:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="14:00">02:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="15:00">03:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="16:00">04:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="17:00">05:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="18:00">06:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="19:00">07:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="20:00">08:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="21:00">09:00 PM</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                           <select name="time_to" id="time_to" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Preferred Time To</option>
                            <option value="07:00">7:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="08:00">8:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="09:00">9:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="10:00">10:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="11:00">11:00 AM</option>
                            <option value="12:00">12:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="13:00">01:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="14:00">02:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="15:00">03:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="16:00">04:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="17:00">05:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="18:00">06:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="19:00">07:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="20:00">08:00 PM</option>
                            <option value="21:00">09:00 PM</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
```